# unable to use thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to start another thread from my `onCreateView` method as follows :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            checkRoot();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

but I'm getting this error in the logcat :

```
06-16 12:52:37.088: E/AndroidRuntime(9707): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-804
06-16 12:52:37.088: E/AndroidRuntime(9707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I know I can use `AsyncTask` but I want to use the above method just for curiosity.

This is the `checkRoot` method :

```
private void checkRoot(){
    Process p;
    try{
        // Preform su to get root privledges
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        // Attempt to write a file to a root-only
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system\n");
        os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/etc/temporary.txt\n");

        // Close the terminal
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        try{
            p.waitFor();
            if(p.exitValue() != 225){
                showToast("ROOTED !");
            } else {
                showToast("not root");
                setContentView(R.layout.no_root);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            showToast("not root");
            setContentView(R.layout.no_root);
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        showToast("not root");
        setContentView(R.layout.no_root);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us checkRoot() method

Comment: Added the `checkRoot()` method.

Comment: you might be updating ui from the thread what does this do showToast("not root");

Comment: It just shows the Toast .. nothing else..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update ui from the background thread. You should update ui from the ui thread.

```
    showToast("not root");
    setContentView(R.layout.no_root);
```

Use runonUithread

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui threa
      {
          public void run() 
          { 

          }
       });
```

Also using setContentView twice for the same activity is not a good desgin. Rethink your design.

You can also use a handler